# Schur-Positivity of a simple polynomial

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-polynomials, characters, toeplitz-matrices, hankel-matrices

Let $\chi_{d,p;f}$ be the following symmetric polynomial,

$$\chi_{d,p;f}(x)=\prod_{l=1}^d\sum_{k=0}^p x_l^{f_k},$$

where $f=\lbrace f_0,\ldots,f_p\rbrace$ is a set of integers. I need to identify for which $f$ values $\chi_{d,p;f}$ is Schur-positive, i.e.:

$$\chi_{d,p;f}(x)=\sum_\rho a_\rho S_\rho(x_1,\ldots,x_d),$$
for $a_\rho$ non-negative integer. I've tried using the orthogonality of the Schur functions under the Haar measure of $U(n)$ to compute the coefficients explicitly $a_\rho=a_\rho(f)$ but the resulting expression is a complicated determinant of a Töplitz$\pm$Hankel matrix. There is any other way to find the Schur-positive cases for this polynomial? or at least some non-trivial $f$ examples?

Comment: A remark which could perhaps help: what you have is the resultant of the polynomial $\sum x^{f_i}$ and the polynomial with coefficients given by the elementary symmetric functions of the $x_i$. The resultant can be written in terms of inverse Kostka matrices https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82032326.pdf  so you might be able to get to the Schur basis via a product of transition matrices between the most common bases for symmetric functions as described in say the book by Macdonald

Comment: Can you say a bit about the context this problem came up?   Anyway $f= \{n \}$ and $f = \{ n, n+1\}$ work and I believe they are the only solutions.

Comment: It came up in a quantum mechanics problem so I cannot say too much more, mathematically speaking. However I don`t follow your intuition, Nate. Why do you think they are the only possible solutions?